# Android: how to give points to the user every hour to be used in the application?

Tags: android

I'm developing an Android application and I encoutered some problems. What I'm trying to do is to give a certain amounts of points to the user every hour. This points are used for some features in the app itself. How could I do that?I'm able to access a database as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could run a timer counting down from `3600` to `0`, and every time it reaches zero you add one to the points and reset the timer. Save the status of the timer and the points in the database or in a file. I'm not sure how efficient this is though.

Comment: What kind of timer? What method have I to use? Thanks

Comment: The best teachers are those who show you where to look, but don't tell you what to see.